# Awk incrementing variable counts 12,615,766 twice

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, cygwin

I have a huge XML table with 706,255,441 lines and 50,446,817 rows.

Each row has 14 lines consisting of 12 columns and 2 with row opening and closing tags.

Now, one of these 12 column lines is a primary key, which is essentially a counter starting at 1 and finishing at 50,446,817... or at least it *should*. Instead, it finishes at 50,446,816, and the verification software says that there's 1 primary key that isn't unique.

Considering that the line number minus 3 (XML stuff) and divided by 14 equals 50,446,817, I know the verification software is right, so why is this happening?

The awk script that I use through a Cygwin terminal is this:

```
awk '{print} sub(/<c11>.*/,""){print "<c12>"++cnt"</c12>"}' FILE
```

I'm aware that the script itself is a bit pointless with the whole substring thing, I have no awk skills and only really recycled it from another script.

Once again, the issue is that the incrementing variable `++cnt` appears to count the same number twice on its way to 50,446,817, and I have confirmed that it's 12,615,766 exactly.

The following type of input would be much appreciated:

- An alternative way of achieving what this awk script is meant to do (make a primary key column)
- An explanation as to why this may be happening
- Any other input you deem relevant

What I have already tried doing to diagnose or solve the problem:

- Printing under a different string, to see if the issue stems from the location not being found (This proved not to be the case)
- Proving that the number of rows is indeed higher than what the counter reaches.
- Figured out which number got repeated.

EDIT:
By popular demand, here is what the 2 rows in this table looks like (I can't include the actual data, as it contains classified information, so all numbers have been replaced with 7 and letters with B/b).

```
    <row>
        <c1>7777777777</c1>
        <c2>BB</c2>
        <c3>03/20/2013 00:00:00</c3>
        <c4>-1</c4>
        <c5>777777</c5>
        <c6>7</c6>
        <c7>01/01/2013 00:00:00</c7>
        <c8>77777777</c8>
        <c9>7.77</c9>
        <c10>77777-Bbbbbbbb Bbbbb</c10>
        <c11>77-</c11>
        <c12>12615766</c12>
    </row>
    <row>
        <c1>7777777777</c1>
        <c2>BB</c2>
        <c3>03/20/2013 00:00:00</c3>
        <c4>-7</c4>
        <c5>777777</c5>
        <c6>7</c6>
        <c7>07</c7>
        <c8>77777777</c8>
        <c9>7.77</c9>
        <c10>77777-Bbbbbbbb Bbbbb</c10>
        <c11>77-</c11>
        <c12>12615766</c12>
    </row>
```

The 12th column is created by the above script, and the next row is placed directly under this. The issue is that the c12 column gets printed with the exact same key when the incrementing variable reached 12,615,766.

Comment: interesting problem. Please update your Q to include output from `awk --version` (or maybe `awk -V` (not -v, that has another use)) and `uname -srv`. You could run a test like `awk 'END{cnt=12615760; while (cnt++<12615770) print "cnt="cnt}' /dev/null` to see if is just this particlar number (not incrementing from `1`) Maybe also `awk 'END{cnt=0; while (cnt++<12615870) print "cnt="cnt}' /dev/null > awkCntTest.out` (note I have gone an extra 100 over on the range on this one). I don't get a gap with either test on my system, but ... who knows.  Good luck.

Comment: Could you update the question with a sample file with a couple of rows?

Comment: fwiw, I ran both of shelter's tests in my cygwin environment and did not generate any duplicates; `uname -srv = CYGWIN_NT-6.1 3.0.7(0.338/5/3) 2019-04-30 18:08`; `awk --version = GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.1.2)`; `bash --version = GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)`

Comment: OK, your tools seem to be completely up-to-date, and you couldn't duplicate your problem with a simple test. We'll need to see a few sample records to try a develop some theories about what is happening. Please update your Q so we can see what you're dealing with. AND of course, processing `XML` in a non-XML aware tool is a ticket to insanity ;-/ . Might be better to find a DB that can parse XML, load it there and reprocess as needed. (Or other XML aware solution). Good luck.

Comment: The most likely issue is that your XML doesn't look like you hope it does (e.g. you have `<c11>` inside a comment or something) and so parsing it without an XML aware tool is unsurprisingly failing on it.

Comment: can add a 3 rows sample of you data , in your questions ?

Comment: Yes, how about the record before, the problem record and the following record. Annoymized if need be. My guess is a NULL char, which may get obscured by editing the data to put it into your Q. So ... no easy answers probably. Focus on the problem record in detail. maybe `grep rec_key data.xml | od -c` will show something that shouldn't be there. Good luck.

Comment: Have you verified that there are no `<c12>` lines in the input before you add them? By the way, you can replace the call to `sub` with a simple regex: `awk '{print} /<c11>/{print "<c12>"++cnt"</c12>"}' FILE`

Comment: @EdMorton I attempted to check for this issue by instead printing under the <row> and </row> tags, but the exact same issue occurred. I also actually looked at the XML at the point where the problem occurs, and there was no obvious reason for it.

Comment: @rici Yes, I have verified this by looking at the exact point that this happens, and there is no formatting issue that accounts for it. Also, thanks for clarifying how that script would look. Like I said, I know that the disabled substring thing is pointless, it was originally meant to make indentations for me, but sub bugged on unknown characters

Comment: @shellter Yeah, the whole setup is really really specific to this exact task. The XML database that I have actually starts out as a super botched csv extract from a large decomissioned database that predates my own career by about a decade, so there's a few steps needed to even turn this into its XML format to begin with, but I am not really creating or working with any of the data, I am simply changing its format and fixing the format breaking bugs. I can paste an example of what a row looks like, minus the confidential data, but I'm not sure it helps.

Comment: @markp I think its a bug in my setup. I am using mintty 3.0.6 (x86_64-pc-cygwin).

Comment: @shellter I posted the 2 rows in my question above, anonymized. As far as I can tell, there's nothing out of the ordinary. No NULL characters either. Like I said, I also tried pasting it in various other parts of the row, and the exact same issue occurred, so it doesn't seem to be caused by the XML at all, but by the AWK script itself.

Comment: Since there is nothing magic about the number `12,615,766` and assuming the awk script you're executing is the same one you posted in your question **the problem is in your input file** and we can't see that so can't help you further. If you can reduce it to a [mcve] and post that in your question then we can help but if you do that you'll probably figure out the problem yourself in the process.

Comment: @edMorton There is no minimal reproducible example. This script counts that number twice, regardless of where I place it in the file, which means that it has nothing to do with the file itself. Most likely, there's an issue with a setting somewhere, or something that interferes. I've even tried a different file, and the problem persists. The issue doesn't seem to be visible at all in the file either, as can clearly be seen by what I wrote above, which is technically the same the real thing, with the exact same number of letters and numbers. My takeaway is that the issue must be my cygwin.

Comment: Your takeaway is wrong. There are only 2 possibilities: 1) There is something unexpected in your input file, or 2) There is a bug in your script. Cygwin is not the issue and there is no setting nor anything else environmental that could produce this behavior. wrt `as can clearly be seen by what I wrote above` - you posted a few lines of text that would not reproduce your problem when your awk script is run against it. As such we cannot see the raw contents of your input file so we can't see what control characters, etc. might be present, nor have you given us anything that we can test with.

Comment: Are you **SURE** that when you run the script in your question (exactly **THAT** script and no other instead of, before or after it) that you get `<c12>12615766</c12>` twice in the output? If so then the problem is definitely your input file. If not then the problem is probably in your script(s). idk why you said `I'm aware that the script itself is a bit pointless with the whole substring thing` btw - that (or maybe something similar but more robust) is what you need to preserve indenting for the `<c12>` line you're adding.

Answer (score 1):

i will use some xml library that can do stream xml parsing .

i will suppose that `c4` is your primary key .

i will extract all primary key , with this perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use XML::Twig;
my $twig=XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers =>
      {  c4  => sub { print $_->text,"\n"; } ,
         row  => sub { $_->purge; }
         } ) ;
$twig->parsefile( 'doc.xml');
```

and redirect the ouput to a file `all_c4.txt`

```
perl parserow.pl > all_c4.txt
```

after i will sort , and count uniq rows

```
sort all_c4.txt | uniq -c > all_c4_with_cnt.txt
```

and i will check rows that are not uniq

```
grep '^ *[2-9] *' all_c4_with_cnt.txt
```

ps: the perl package i used is from https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig

Comment: Useful method for finding the duplicate. Thanks for that.
I already did find the duplicate now though, and patched the issue manually. What I am left wondering is why this happened in the first place. It seems like my exact setup just has an inherent mistake when incrementing past this exact number. Odd.

Comment: @Noobie : So there was a duplicate record in your data? (Just would like some closure on this issue). Glad if you have solved your problem. Good luck to all.